# Get VS2008 to "tree-indent" partial classes (like code-behind files)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-behind

I have created a multi plattform project, and everything works nicely, except one little things. When I add a specific plattform file, like:

- ServiceImpl.cs
- ServiceImpl.Desktop.cs

it does not show up nicely in a tree fashion like in this article:

[Multi-Targeting](http://www.mokosh.co.uk/post/Prism-2-WPF-and-Silverlight-Multi-Platform-Targeting.aspx) (check the last image in the article to understand what I mean)..

Any ideas how to "teach" VS 2008 to do this? With normal XAML and Code-Behind it works as usual...

---

Ok, the answer worked perfect for a normal situation. Now, there is still a little problem with the silverlight project. The file is originally located in the desktop project, so there the solution works. However, if the "parent" file is a link, it seems to cause a problem (no effect at all)... See this code:

```
<Compile Include="..\Messaging\Services\MessagingService.cs">
  <Link>Services\MessagingService.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
<Compile Include="Services\MessagingService.Silverlight.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MessagingService.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Any ideas for this situation?

Comment: I don't think it works with the linked file... sorry...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't always do it automatically (although it spots things like .Designer.), but you can edit the csproj by hand to do this (it is just xml). There are also a few add-ins that provide this, but the one I use has been removed. You want DependentUpon...

```
<Compile Include="ServiceImpl.cs" />
<Compile Include="ServiceImpl.Desktop.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ServiceImpl.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

(note they must be in the same folder; you don't specify the folder in DependentUpon)

Comment: Thanks, worked... Still little problem with a linked file, see edit above.. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin http://mokosh.co.uk/vscommands/
to group items in solution explorer from VS (without editing project file).