# How to associate a Resx file to a class in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, resx

How do I associate/"bind" an resx file to a class file in Visual Studio?
For example, when a new windows form is created, an resx file is automatically associated with it.

[image]

I am asking this as the following code doesn't open the right resource file for another .cs file I have:

```
ComponentResourceManager manager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyClass));
```

This code works fine for frmLogin from above however.

The MSDN documentation for the constructor:

> Creates a ComponentResourceManager
>   that looks up resources in satellite
>   assemblies based on information from
>   the specified Type.

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043467/get-vs2008-to-tree-indent-partial-classes-like-code-behind-files/1043482#1043482

Answer (score 1):

That a form has an associated .resx file is an implementation detail that's specific to forms.  You cannot otherwise associate an arbitrary class with a .resx file.  I assume that you actually want to use a ResourceManager here.

Do note that there's one already built-in through Properties.Resources, giving you access to resources that you added to Project + Properties, Resources tab.

Answer (score 0):

Should you have lost this indenting by adding existing files to a project, you can restore the indenting for files, though I have not tried it for all file types, by using the 'DependentUpon' node in the project file.

The technique is described in more detail at Code rant: [Nested files with 'DependentUpon' in Visual Studio](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/11/nested-files-with-dependentupon-in.html)

I found an [existing answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043482/19308) since discovering the article above, but as the question is formulated so differently I'm keeping this answer in place.